# iOS-charts stacked bar chart with multiple colors

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart with different colors for each bar. It works fine if I provide only two colors in the `BarChartDataSet`, or if I have a normal bar chart with a color for every bar. However I wonder how I can provide two colors for each `BarChartDataEntry` in the data set?

Comment: how did you end up subclassing `BarChartRenderer`?...I'm trying to do the same but I don't know what to pass into the parameter `drawValues(context: CGContext)` for `context`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at ChartsDemo's stacked bar chart view controller:
Just feed the colors to BarChartDataSet.colors

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    double mult = (range + 1);
    double val1 = (double) (arc4random_uniform(mult) + mult / 3);
    double val2 = (double) (arc4random_uniform(mult) + mult / 3);
    double val3 = (double) (arc4random_uniform(mult) + mult / 3);

    [yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValues:@[@(val1), @(val2), @(val3)] xIndex:i]];
}

BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals label:@"Statistics Vienna 2014"];
set1.colors = @[ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom[0], ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom[1], ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom[2]];
set1.stackLabels = @[@"Births", @"Divorces", @"Marriages"];
```

In bar chart renderer it is using this colors array to fill each segment,

```
// Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index is out of bounds, reuse colors.
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, dataSet.colorAt(k).CGColor)
```

If you want each bar has different color, then you have to use multiple data sets and perhaps adjust `barSpace` and `groupSpace`

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough, I meant having a stacked chart where each bar has different colors. The example works fine, as long as I want all the bars to have the same three colors, but that's not the case.

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you want each bar has different color, then you have to use multiple data sets and perhaps adjust `barSpace` and `groupSpace`

Comment: With two data sets I end up having bars which occupy half of the space of the normal bar (which is expected because I have two data sets and only one provides a value for a given index), but how can I tweak the `barSpace` and `groupSpace` variables so every bar occupies the full width of the bar? I know that I will never have two bars for the same index.

Comment: you have to let every dataset has entry for every xIndex, or you will have plenty of white space. you can change the rendering logic if you want ultimate control

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up subclassing `BarChartRenderer` and overriding `drawDataSet( context context: CGContext, dataSet: IBarChartDataSet, index: Int )`